# Does Nhibernate support Sybase?

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, sybase

I'm about to start on a new WPF application with a Sybase datastore. The team has experience with Nhibernate, but we are not really sure how well it supports Sybase and if there are some major pitfalls we should look out for.

If yes, how about Fluent nhibernate?

If not, do you know any other ORM products that we could use for Sybase in this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/category/database-interfaces/nhibernate/), I would say that it does. There seems to have known issues, though. But depending on what you need, it might suit your needs.

The [SQLAnywhere12Dialect](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2010/01/new-sql-anywhere-12-nhibernate-dialect/) seems to have repaired some of the buggy stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Sybase is officially supported in NHibernate.

From what I've seen, Fluent NH doesn't expose a class for configuring a Sybase DB, but you can probably do that in a just couple of lines (the rest of it is not dependent on the DB)

Comment: This might be of help: http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/c5b1b468ce10df20/a010bbe127306c7f?lnk=gst&q=sybase#a010bbe127306c7f

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about Sybase ASE or Sybase Anywhere. NHibernate supports both and FluentNHibernate supports neither.

Comment: I was asking about Sybase ASE. Have you used Nhibernate with Sybase ASE?

Comment: We are currently using NHibernate with Sybase ASE. The drivers are targeted at version 11, so if you are using any features from 12 or 15, you will need to tweak the drivers just a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to correct the statements made here, even though this is an older post. NHibernate does **NOT exactly** support Sybase.

As a reference for why I say this statment please look here:
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate

Granted that post is from 2009. NHibernate has since released version 3.0 which does have dialects available for Sybase:
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/12/05/nhibernate-3-0-released.aspx

But the issue here is it is only for Sybase Anywhere, so if you have ASE you will have to refer to Glenn Paulley's independent releases for NHibernate, and I do not believe he is actually affiliated with NHibernate.

All this being said, I've tried for the past few hours to get what is out there working with Sybase ASE 15 and I've been unsuccessful. Looks like I'll just make my own with the .NET drivers provided.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Joseph's answer:

I downloaded the binaries for NHibernate 3.2.0.GA about two weeks ago (about 10/5/2011) and it didn't seem to come with ASE 15 support out of the box (no dialect or drivers, closest one maybe being SQL Anywhere).

This issue was [reported in their Jira.](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2526)

Today (10/20/2011) I downloaded the source code for the project to try to add my own and I found out that there are classes now that offer this support, SybaseASE15Dialect.cs and SybaseASEDriver.

I'm not sure if the binaries now have this support, but if not you can just download the source files, build the NHibernate project and use the dlls, or just wait until they make a new release with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a similar project using NHibernate, and using ODBC to connect to Sybase SQL Anywhere, it works fine with the "GenericDialect".
Here's some sample code to build your session factory.

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());
HbmMapping mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()
                    .DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                    {
                        db.ConnectionString = connectionStr;
                        db.Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.GenericDialect>();
                        db.Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver>();
                    });
    
cfg.AddMapping(mapping);
cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```