# Does Nhibernate support Sybase ASE?

Tags: nhibernate, sap-ase

I am currently using nhibernate 3.1 with ms sql server 2005. In the same project, i have need to connect to legacy databse - Sybase ASE 15.

Does nhibernate support sys
base ase and if so is it stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase ASE is [officially](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Driver) [supported](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/SybaseASE15Dialect.cs). Since NHibernate is open-source, you can easily browse it on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core) mirror and see what databases [it supports](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect).

As for the stability, [Sybase ASE 15 support](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2526) is there since early NHibernate 3.2 version, and looks like Sybase employees are [overlooking](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/?cat=51) and/or maintaining Sybase support for NHibernate.

Another SO question that might help:
[Does Nhibernate support Sybase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997787/does-nhibernate-support-sybase)

Comment: Thanks Miroslav! I think i will need to upgrade to NH 3.2 version!